# Erigeron not flowering

Tags: plant-health

I have a few Erigeron plants in my garden which are about 3 years old. This year they are producing many buds which are not developing into flowers. The petals appear stunted. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: A photo could help. Where do you live? Maybe it is just the weather,

Comment: I live in Bucks. UK. Unfortunately I cannot see how to attach a photo in this message. Can you advise?